# ODBC Storage Size

Tags: odbc, size, storage

I'm pulling a lot of text from a MS SQL Server database. I'm not getting all the text (which includes some html. The text is stored perfectly on the database. However, when I run the query to get the data It will only pull part of the text.

I pull the data using odbc_exec and store using $variable = odbc_result($runquery,"body").

if i display the content with odbc_result_all($runquery) i get part of the content.

if I use echo $body; i get part of the content then some garbage and part of the text from the begining. very strange response.

Is there a size limit? Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked exactly how much you are getting?  My guess is that it's either 4KB or 8KB.

Also, what is the column type? TEXT, varchar(max), ?

Probably the first thing I would do is download the latest MDAC.  You might want to [check this page out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131035.aspx).

Comment: turns out the php was limiting how much memory was allocated to each variable.